# Jersey HK2 : Dependency injection and healthchecks

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, monitoring, hk2, health-check

My app has got quite a few of async (`cron`) processes and they all have their separate `binder` classes in Jersey. These processes are started and managed through independent scripts.

Now, if I make a change in the classes used by these processes, (e.g. add a dependency in the classes) and forget to update the `binder` class inadvertently, the processes still start up but fail with `org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException` (which is expected). However, this does not stop the process on the node and monitoring tool still thinks that the process is running fine.

I am looking to implement Healthchecks in these process so that I can see if the process has come up fine after deployment and is able to start without any dependency error. I am exploring following options:

- An async lightweight process that exports `ServiceLocator` health status to a monitoring system (e.g. prometheus)
- An API endpoint that can be polled externally and returns response based on `ServiceLocator` status

I have got a couple of questions:

- Is there a native way in `Jersey HK2` to do this?
- How do I know if Locator is able to resolve all the dependencies (i.e. there is no `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`)?

Answer (score 1):

In hk2 there is a special service called the [ErrorService](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ErrorService.html) which you can use to see if there are failures creating services.  Since hk2 is a dynamic framework this error service implementation will not get called until someone attempts to create the service that is failing.

You also might want to seriously look into the automatic binding options of hk2.  Makes *everything* so much easier IMO.  See the section on [Automatic Service Population](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/getting-started.html)

Here is an example of using the ErrorService:

```
@Service
public class ExampleErrorService implements ErrorService {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ErrorInformation ei) throws MultiException {
        if (ErrorType.SERVICE_CREATION_FAILURE.equals(ei.getErrorType())) {
            // Tell your health check service there was an exception
            return;
        }
            
        // Maybe log other failures?
        
    }
    
}
```